# 8085 Microprocessor programming kit

Tags: 8085

When the power of the kit 8085 trading kit is turn on, UP-85 is displayed. How is it possible something is displayed even before entering anything?

Comment: So, you bought a kit that came in pre-programmed and you are surprised it displayed somethings in an LCD display?

Comment: No, I mean, everytime I switch it on or after pressing RESET button,it  displays UP-85. Why is it so.

Comment: read the comment from @jDAQ again, very carefully

Comment: Yeah, it was pre programmed.

Comment: @user676260 .... sooo ... pre-programmed == program running on it. So?

Answer (score 1):

it's probably code in the monitor ROM: something needs to run to make the keypad work.

Entering code by punching in hex or toggling switches gets tedious fast,
so trainers for Von-neuman processors like 8085 typically profide a means to load student software into ram from an externmal source (like a PC) and facilitatre this by means of an interface cable and some ROM code

Comment: We had something very similar in University for 8051 development//learning boards - there was a bootloader code which allows code to be downloaded into the EEPROM (I think it was another flash memory chip actually) over Serial as opposed to progrmaming the 8051 chip itself via parallel or Serial ISP

Answer (score 0):

Microprocessor kit has a pre-written program in ROM (commonly known as Bootstrap Loader) like BIOS program in Laptop/ Desktop that tells the kit what to do when it is turned ON. The ROM is fed with a program to display "UP 8085" short-form (Microprocessor- there is no "mheu" sign so U is used for mheu)